# Convert TKinter Into an Exe File

Tags: python, tkinter

As I was creating a program using python (tkinter), I am unable to convert it into executable form (`.exe)`.

My program uses several images, a bitmap icon and widgets.

I tried `cx_freeze`. It compiles well and generates `exe` and other files but doesn't run. I tried `cx_freeze` with several setup codes but it displays the error related to those images (maybe it don't support images compilation) when I execute it.

I tried searching for an answer, but the solution was related to those tkinter programs that uses only basic widgets but not images in it.

So is there any way or method to convert the tkinter program (that uses images also) into exe file ?

My script for `exe` is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
sys.argv.append("build")
filename = "program.py"
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = "Unick Locker",
    version = "2.0",
    description = "a GUI app that helps you securing your files and data with many functions",
    executables = [Executable(filename, base=base)])
```

Comment: What errors where you getting? And my I also suggest cx_Freeze.

Comment: does it compiles the programs that uses images too ?

Comment: it displays the same error. i cant compile it to exe. any method that could work please

Comment: Did you specify the images with the `data_files` option? Edit your question to include the script your use to create the exe

Comment: no i didn't specify the data_files to the script. i have no idea about it. my script is above in the question

Comment: I thought you were using py2exe. have a look at this for setting it up [Py2exe Docs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions)

Comment: yeah i tried using py2exe also. but it didn't work. it works fine for program without images. i am really stuck. can you please tell me how to use data_files ?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend py2exe, I use it and it works flawlessly.

This is a youtube video that explains how to use it. (i cant insert links as im on a mobile)

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VKQ1Ph81Gps

Any errors just ask, I use it quite enough to know.

Comment: Please let me know in the comments if it helped :D

Comment: thanks for your effort but it isn't the solution i was looking for. That method donot support images and gives the error :)